# Filestream detecting duplicate records

Tags: spark-streaming

I am developing a spark streaming application based on filestream...I need to actually detect the duplicate records in the DStream (RDDs.)

I want to possibly do it using just memory..First, thinking about an accumulator but not sure if accumulators can keep a large number of records (a look up table with hashing of CSV records).

I wanted to know how I can have a large and global mutable collection in my spark streaming application?

Comment: You can use `mapWithState` for this. You can keep a key-value pair of some identifier mapped to the value, which can be a hash or any sort of thing you'd like. Then, as part of your pipeline, `mapWithState` can check for duplicates, and only output values which aren't.

Comment: I am dealing with large amount of data..so in that case my application will soon keep to consume large amount of memory..considering at least key and states should be kept in memory (is that right?) and there is no timing out to be set..

Comment: But you can "deprecate" old records at every interval you want.

Comment: what do you mean from deprecate?..you mean removing states?..in my case I receive records indefinitely..